# How to get a file from Icloud in Xamarin c#?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to get a file from ICloud in Xamarin/c#. I have googled a lots of but I don't find any answer.

I only need to get a file if that is exists. For example databaseExport.zip 
But I don't know how to open that file from ICloud if it's exists.

On Ipad I can save my zip file to ICloud only. That's good. But I need to open that zip file with that application I'm working on.

I tried to understood this one: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_icloud/
But I'm not sure if it can helps me.

Comment: That link explains perfectly how to upload/download a document from icloud, is just what you're asking. You need to download the file and uncompress it, using a temp file or a memory stream.

Comment: Looking for the same thing. Have you found a solution? That link is really bad for a real application. It explains only the useless "example", but not the mechanics for an iOS noob like me.